# Getting a list of custom Visualforce components

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, visualforce-component

I am trying to write a class that will list all custom Visualforce components in an .org on a page.

I see that my custom components are included in the component reference at https://myorg.salesforce.com/apexpages/apexcomponents.apexp

But I would like to get the list of just custom components programatically so I can display them on a custom page. Does anyone know how to do this? What I should query or how else I can go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the ApexComponent Object documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexcomponent.htm)

Here is the sample query for same

```
[SELECT ApiVersion,ControllerKey,
   ControllerType,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Id,Markup,
  MasterLabel,Name,NamespacePrefix FROM ApexComponent]
```

I executed in execute anonymous to see if this also runs in apex and it does work

```
system.debug('Result'+[SELECT ApiVersion,ControllerKey,ControllerType,Markup,MasterLabel,Name FROM ApexComponent]);
```

Comment: This trick also works for other types of code as well. It's a great way to find stuff by way of Apex Code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, works like a charm. I know it seems like a simple question, but there are so many things I Google and just can't find the documentation for what I want......